# Toggle mouselook in Final Fantasy XIV

Tags: final-fantasy-14

*Final Fantasy XIV* doesn't support mouselook, i.e. where you can turn the camera and the character without holding the right mouse button. What are the possible solutions?

Comment: On a related note, there is a "steer" keybind that you can use, it acts like moving forward but locks your mouse movements to moving both the camera and the character.

Answer (score 3):

1. Install [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).
2. Create a file named `ff14.ahk` with this content:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 3

#IfWinActive FINAL FANTASY XIV

; Left Control switch

RmbHold := false
LCtrl::
  RmbHold := !RmbHold
  if RmbHold {
      send {RButton down}
  } else {
      send {RButton up}
  }
return

; Mapping RMB to the controller A/X for easier interaction without a mouse cursor on screen

RButton::
  if RmbHold {
      send {G}
  } else {
      send {RButton down}
  }
return

RButton Up::
  if !RmbHold {
      send {RButton up}
  }
return

; Automatically turn off the RMB-holding on Alt-Tab to avoid messing up other applications

!Tab::
  if RmbHold {
      RmbHold := false
      send {RButton up}    
  }
  send {Alt down}{Tab}
return

!Tab Up::
  send {Alt up}
return
```

3. In FF, go to 'System - Keybinds - Gamepad - X Button' (or 'A Button' for Xbox gamepad) and bind it to <kbd>PgDn</kbd> (page down key).
4. Keep `ff14.ahk` running while you're playing FF.

Now, when in-game:

1. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> ingame will toggle between mouselook and having the cursor on the screen, and
2. Pressing RMB will act like the gamepad's 'X', that is:

   - If you don't have a target selected it will select what's in front of you - both an enemy, a neutral NPC, an interactable world object, etc.
   - If you got a target selected and it's an enemy, it will start autoattacking.
   - If it's an interactable object/NPC it will interact with it.
   - If you're in a dialogue it will skip the current dialogue line.